# where to syphon off voltage from a 25 pin serial?

Tags: serial, power

I have a mircocontroller that's looking to be powered by a 5v source.

I am trying to 'cypher off' some of this power from a 25 pin serial port, which is being powered by a constant power source.

Are there any pins that could give me that sort of voltage, or enough to power the board?

[image]

Please note, I'm **not an electrical person** at all, and so hope this is actually possible (otherwise my 3 months + program's work doesn't really add to anything).

I've tried a 9v battery, but it didn't seem to hold its charge?

I'm reading these labels going "what the ..." so you can probably tell coding the board wasn't the easiest, either.

**Edit History**

- *I would like to clarify this is an **existing serial lead***
- *I understand this may be deemed verging off topic,* *but due to the need to 'power' a* *microcontroller, I thought this could be answered here*
- *If this isn't possible, (as an alternative, possibly) would a 9V/battery be able to power this board reliably for around 2-3 weeks?*

Comment: Pins 11/18 might be NC so you could add your own adapter on the other side to send power through unused lines. If not, the only real thing I can see is using pin 9 and a regulator. I'm not sure how much that pin is rated for, though. I probably won't damage anything with 100 mA though....

Comment: @AnnonomusPenguin: Sorry if this is a stupid question, but what'd you mean by a 'regulator'. Like, i know what it means in English, but physically what?

Comment: I meant using the onboard linear regulator. When you connect a power supply to VIN or the black power jack that's over ~7.5V the Arduino converts that to a 5V for it to use. In this case, you might be able to connect pin 9 on the serial wire to the VIN pin on the Arduino and the ground wire on the cable to the GND pin on the Arduino and it would convert it to 5V for it to use.

Comment: You need 5 volts; A serial port uses higher voltages (usually 12v but apparently there is some latitude). A voltage regulator is a circuit that provides a stable 5 volts (in this case) from a higher and not necessarily constant voltage. (For completeness, there are also regulators that provide a higher voltage than their source, but that isn't what you need here).

Comment: It is unclear from your question whether you are trying to get power from an existing serial port, or merely use it for transport. The diagram you posted MAY have been relevant 40 years ago, but NO  current microcomputer equipment would support this - indeed this is why most equipment uses a 9 pin connector, and even these are rare. One thing that is clear is that you do not understand the interface. Even in the good old days you COULD NOT derive power from serial. Equipment no longer supports the voltages in the standard, which was meant to operate over 1000m.

Comment: @Milliways - no, the person who does not understand the interface is *you*.  Drawing **small amounts** of power from serial interfaces was quite normal.  It's a moot point though, as this question is not on topic for the Arduino site.

Comment: @ChrisStratton: It's in that grey area of topicality, since it's about powering the board from serial. So, i personally would agree there is an iffy point. But I hope this *could* be solved?

Comment: This is off topic because it is not asked about an Arduino, and because nothing sold *as* an "arduino" would be particularly suitable for this use.  Your question belongs on EESE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to use pin 7 for negative, 9 as positive, this gives you 12 volts.

YOU MUST NOT HOOK THIS UP DIRECTLY to the arduino, connect it to a plug for the power jack (right of the USB connection).

If you are using a USB -> serial adapter, then the voltage may be 5v, but don't count on it.

Of course, USB is always going to be better!

PS - if you draw more power than the serial port is rated for, you will probably destroy the card. In most cases, this will be the motherboard. You are unlikely to be able to find out what it is rated for (look for Amps or A, or milliAmps  mA, or microAmps uA). The Arduino (with NO inputs or outputs, and idle) running from a 9v battery will draw about 50 milliAmps.

Comment: No.  You are quite unlike to "destroy the card" by drawing more power, as the port drivers simply can't supply much power to begin with, and I/O drivers are typically designed to be robust, because people do silly things like wire up mistaken cables, using straight cables where they should use null modems, or null modems where they should use straight cables.  The 1488 data sheet says "current limited" and the MAX232 says output short circuit duration unlimited.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense :) I thought it better to err on the side of caution. It also encourages checking specs, which is a good habit to get into.

Comment: @AMADANONInc.: I can't seem to 'get' a voltage from pin 9... I'm guessing the 'other end' either doesn't connect to anything, or doesn't carry a voltage?

Comment: A 25 pin serial cable doesn't have to be connected to anything standard.  I often used 25 pin serial cables that only had 3 wired pins (2, 3, and 7).  That is sufficient for software flowcontrol serial communications.  If the equipment on the other end doesn't wire up pin 9, then you can't use it.

Answer (score 0):

In a lot of further research, I have discovered that 'It doesn't really matter' what the serial port diagram says, since in 25 pin serials (and 9 pin D-subs), it all depends on the circuit at the other end, showing which wires are actually '*connected*', or '*used*'.

---

I managed to get *some* current from +pin 6 -pin 5 in which allowed me to draw *some* current, but have chosen to go with a (PP3?) 9v battery instead due to its reliability.

---

So, in conclusion to this question, there isn't a specific answer, since it all depends on how the serial at the other end is wired.

It seems to me that in my case, there were minimal wires actually connected, so I was forced to look for other means of connecting to a 'reliable' power source.